# Sampling low pass filtered white noise

Tags: random

If we filter out ideal white noise using an ideal LPF of cutoff frequency 10 KHz and then sample it at 30 KHz , is the resulting discrete signal statistically independent? I would like to know the statistical behaviour of the output signal.

I was attending an on-line test. My answer was told wrong.Below is the snapshot from the on-line test.

[image]

I would also like to know what would be the result if sampling frequency is below Nyquist frequency?

Comment: No, it wouldn't be "statistically independent" or uncorrelated, as I would prefer to say. If you sampled it with 20 kHz then it would be.

Comment: Keeping in mind that statistical independence and uncorrelated-ness are two different things, with the former implying the latter but not vise-versa. But indeed, in DSP contexts the latter is usually what we're interested in.

Comment: I have made an edit (an addition) in the question.

Comment: @Jazzmaniac : Below Nyquist frequency it will be correlated and above Nyquist rate the discrete will be uncorrelated right? When will it be statistically independent and orhtogonal?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The output of your filter is what is sometimes called band-limited white noise. In
your particular case, the autocorrelation function of the output noise is a sinc
function whose zeroes are every $100$ microseconds, that is, samples taken at
the rate of $10^4$ samples/second are uncorrelated.  Your samples at $3\times 10^4$
samples per second are closer together and thus are *correlated*.  In fact,
the correlation coefficient between successive samples is 
$\displaystyle \frac{\sin(\pi/3)}{\pi/3} = \frac{3\sqrt{3}}{2\pi} \approx 0.827$

Note added after question was edited: Samples taken $0.03$ milliseconds apart
are at a frequency of $33.33\ldots$ kHz, not $30$ kHz as you say in the
part of the question that you typed in yourself. Regardless, the answer (B) is
*incorrect* and the reasoning given in support of answer (B)
is bogus. What is being sampled is
*not* white noise but *filtered* white noise, and Answer A is correct.

For (B) to be the correct answer,
the sampling rate must be a *sub-multiple* of $10$ kilosamples per second,
that is the samples must be spaced $100$ microseconds apart
or an *integer* multiple of $100$ microseconds
apart.  Sampling every $0.3$ milliseconds, that is, every $300$ microseconds 
meets this criterion; sampling every $0.03$ milliseconds does not.
Now sampling at $10$ kilosamples/second  makes the samples *uncorrelated* 
(answer (C)) and to get from this to the *stronger* result that
the samples are *statistically independent* (answer (B)), we need
*further* assumptions about the noise. The standard assumption is
that the noise is Gaussian.

> In summary, (B) would be the correct answer
>   if the sampling were done every $0.3$ milliseconds (since the problem
>   statement already includes the assertion that the noise is Gaussian)
>   and (C) would be the correct answer if it did not say that the noise
>   is Gaussian since we could not the make the specialization from
>   uncorrelated to independent.
>   But when the sampling is done every $0.03$ milliseconds, then (A)
>   is the correct answer.

Comment: If you have any suggestion of references for me to see the explanation for this topic elaborately, please kindly share. I can grasp this but it will take time.

Comment: @dexterdev As I said in answer to a different question, More than what you probably want to know about white Gaussian noise
can be found in the Appendix of [this lecture 
note](http://courses.engr.illinois.edu/ece361/sp2011/Newlectures/Lecture03.pdf)
of mine.

Comment: Sir, If I am not troubling you, can you just show me by math that how as sampling frequencies vary the properties like correlation, uncorrelation , statistical independence etc are attained. Also how you arrived at the correlation coefficient of 0.827 ie sinc(pi/3)...How pi/3 comes? Sir I know you are a busy person and I don't want to disturb you. When you are free please show the math behind this. I didn't understand the sub-multiple theory etc.

Comment: The correlation coefficient of two noise samples (separated in time by $t$ seconds) from bandlimited white noise is $\operatorname{sinc}(t/T)= \frac{\sin(\pi (t/T))}{\pi (t/T)}$ where $T=1/W$ is the minimum separation that gives zero correlation and $W$ is the bandwidth of the noise. In your case, $W=10^4, T=10^{-4}, t=(3\times 10^{4})^{-1} = (1/3)\times 10^{-4}$ since _you_ claim a sampling rate of $30$ kHz (the _problem_ says the sampling interval is $3\times 10^{-4}$). The correlation for _your_ sampling interval is $\sin(\pi/3)/(\pi/3)$; for the _problem_, it is different but $\neq 0$

Comment: Can I get a link/reference of the derivation this correlation coefficient.

Comment: For $B=10\,\text{kHz}$, the zeros of the sinc function are every $50\mu s$, not $100\mu s$. This caused some confusion in [this question](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/24874/sampling-of-band-limited-white-noise).

Answer (score 3):

If by 'resulting discrete signal statistically independent' you mean whether the samples will be independent, i.e. whether $P(x[1],x[2],\dots,x[N]) = \prod_{i=1}^N P(x[i])$, the answer is in general no, because the filtering will induce correlations between nearby elements: the LPF operation means that values of successive elements can't change arbitrarily quickly, hence not independent.